# Kotlin запуск в IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

Собственно, не хочет запускать и адекватно воспринимать функции. К тому же при запуске main() запускает функцию из другого пакета, которую я редактировал ранее, хотя эта функция нигде не вызывается. Так же, функция main() тоже не работает, если я пишу ее вручную (а не создаю через main и нажатие tab)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Выберите файл с необходимой Вам функцией `main` и нажмите <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>
Скорей всего вы просто не поменяли файл для запуска в выпадающем списке рядом с зеленой стрелкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]